# is there a way to create route53_zone and apply its zone_id to records at the same time in terraform?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-route53

I'm very new to coding and terraform.

I was trying to write every resource I needed to .tf file

while doing so, I

```js
Terraform plan
```

and got an error

```js
│ Error: no matching Route53Zone found
│
│   with data.aws_route53_zone.<name>,
│   on <filename>.tf line 70, in data "aws_route53_zone" "<name>":
│   70: data "aws_route53_zone" "<name>" {
```

And this is what I wrote

```js
resource "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
    name       = "example.com"
    comment    = "eg-example"

    tags= {
        Name = "example.com"
    }
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate" "eg-example-acm-domaincert" {
    domain_name               = "*.example.com"
    validation_method         = "DNS"
    tags = {
      name = "eg-example-acm-domaincert"
      }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cname-example" {
    zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
    name    = "cname.example.com"
    type    = "CNAME"
    records = ["cname-example-alb-ext-1111111111.region.elb.amazonaws.com"]
    ttl     = "300"

}

data "aws_route53_zone" "example" {
  name         = "example.com."
  private_zone = true
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "eg-example-acm-domaincert" {
  certificate_arn         = "arn:aws:acm:**********************"
  validation_record_fqdns = ["*****************************.example.com"]
}
```

the code was not so different from this.

I really don't have any idea besides creating a zone on the AWS console.

is there any other way?

I hope my explanation makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of your call to `data` and just use the resource:

`aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id`

Use `data` when you're retrieving a resource you've previously created (from another Terraform project, for example).

```
    
resource "aws_route53_record" "cname-example" {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id // no need for data.
    name    = "cname.example.com"
    type    = "CNAME"
    records = ["cname-example-alb-ext-1111111111.region.elb.amazonaws.com"]
    ttl     = "300"

}
```

Run `terraform validate` and `terraform plan`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating your HZ in your TF script, you can refer to it as well, without using data source:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cname-example" {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example.zone_id
    name    = "cname.example.com"
    type    = "CNAME"
    records = ["cname-example-alb-ext-1111111111.region.elb.amazonaws.com"]
    ttl     = "300"

}
```